# Implement Google Maps Live Camera View in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, google-maps, google-maps-sdk-ios

**Hi Developers**

I am trying to implement **Google Maps Live Camera View** in iOS as shown in below Image:

[image]

Also, Have a look at what **Google Maps** has presented [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ip_SV70WFO0):

**Note:**

- I have Google Maps Keys.
- I am running App on Real iPhone.
- Using Xcode 14.3.
- Installed **pod 'GoogleMaps'**
- I am in India. (Not sure if this feature is available or not)

Is there any property or Class available to enable Live Camera mode or it is not available?

**I have implemented the normal Map here:**

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition(
  latitude: -33.8683,
  longitude: 151.2086,
  zoom: 160
  
)
self.mapView = GMSMapView.map(withFrame: self.streetView.bounds, camera: camera)
self.mapView.mapType = .satellite
self.mapView.isMyLocationEnabled = true
self.mapView.settings.myLocationButton = true
self.locationManager.delegate = self
self.locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
self.locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
self.streetView.addSubview(self.mapView)
```

**Thanks in advance to all contributors.**